# CodeIgniter Dynamic Method Calls

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a database with some "filters"; i.e. method calls and want to be able to call them dynamically dependent on what the user has input.

Code Igniter does not seem to like this however, any ideas?
It outputs:
In GetEmailCountfilter_male_count():

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined property: Targeted_Email::$filter_male_count()</p>
<p>Filename: core/Model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 51</p>

{"emailCount":null}
```

Code:

```
 public function getEmailCount($filter){
      echo 'In GetEmailCount';
      $result = array();
      $query = $this->db->get('base_targeted_email_filters');


      foreach ($query->result() as $row){
           if($filter == $row->name){

                $test = $row->filterCountFunction . "()";
                     echo $test;
                $result['emailCount'] = $this->{$test};
           }

  return $result
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The foreach loop should be like this:

```
$test = $row->filterCountFunction;
$this->{$test}();
```

Comment: Its because property name should not start with a number but with string. So we need to warp in curly braces to make numeric property valid.

Comment: @user254153 no, it's not because it starts with a number, I don't even understand why would you comment that here.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why we need curly braces there. Because I have seen that when property is in numeric and we can access with after wraping property with curly braces.

Comment: @user254153 because in the question `$test` becomes the value of the property `filterCountFunction` (which is unset) concatenated to 2 braces characters `()`

Answer (score 0):

The below code will work.

```
  public function getEmailCount($filter){
  echo 'In GetEmailCount';
  $result = array();
  $query = $this->db->get('base_targeted_email_filters');


  foreach ($query->result() as $row){
       if($filter == $row->name){

            $test = $row->filterCountFunction . "()";
                 echo $test;
            $result['emailCount'] = $this->$test;
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for your responce, however I still get the same output :S Could this be something to do with how code igniter handles this?

Comment: Can you try call_user_func($test) or call_user_func($this->$test) instead of $this->$test;

Comment: filter_male_count<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'filter_male_count' not found or invalid function name</p>
<p>Filename: models/base_targeted_email_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 253</p>

</div>{"emailCount":null}

Comment: that code really looks wrong.. `$row->filterCountFunction . "()"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to call the dynamic function with parameters

```
$result['emailCount'] = call_user_func('filter_function_name',$parameters);
```

Comment: I'll have a try with your method after work and let you know :) Thanks for the suggestion :)